# KProperty1 (Kotlin)

Tags: kotlin, generics

Explain some things to me...
I have a model:

```
data class Book (val title: String, val id: Int)
```

MutableList:

```
var books = mutableListOf<Book>()
```

I want fill `textView.text` from mutablelist books, field "title"

```
Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post {
    textView.text = books.map { Book ::title }.reduce { acc, s ->  "$acc\n$s"}.toString()
}
```

In final I have Error ("reduce" is marked):

```
None of the following substitutions
receiver: Iterable<KProperty1<Book, String>>  arguments: ((Any, KProperty1<Book, String>) -> Any)
receiver: Iterable<KProperty1<Book, String>>  arguments: ((KProperty1<Book, String>, KProperty1<Book, String>) -> KProperty1<Book, String>)
can be applied to
receiver: List<KProperty1<Book, String>>  arguments: ((KProperty1<Book, String>, KProperty1<Book, String>) -> String)
```

How to solve this problem

Answer (score 3):

If you use the map function by passing a literal function, don't wrap it in a lambda, because then you're passing a function that simply returns a function without doing anything.

So, change

```
books.map { Book ::title }
```

to

```
books.map(Book::title)
```

Also, there is already a `joinToString` function you can use that is simpler than using `reduce` to create a single String from an Iterable. You can use it like this:

```
books.map(Book::title).joinToString("\n")
```